# Difference between [parsing] and [extracting]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have 7 [parsing](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) questions (with 8 followers) and 9 [extracting](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extracting) questions (with 3 followers). Is there really a difference between these two tags? Or should we merge them instead? If so, which one should we keep?

Also, Wikipedia defines *parsing* as `the process of analysing a string of symbols, either in natural language or in computer languages, conforming to the rules of a formal grammar`. Looking through our current [parsing](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) questions, I'm not sure that any of them fit this definition.

What do you think?

Answer (score 6):

Parsing and extracting are distinct for me. Extracting is the collecting (downloading), while parsing is the transformation (e.g. "[ETL - Extract, Transform, Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)").

---

Some examples of how I see it:

**Extracting** - collecting data

- [Monthly data in Google Trends](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4234/1511)
- [What is the best way to get airline schedule data from pdf files](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1053/1511)
- [Wikipedia table to JSON (or other machine-readable format)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/823/1511)

**Parsing** - turning data into information

- [Good tools to parse repetitive unstructured data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/92/1511)
- [Parsing Curriculum Vitaes](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1572/1511) (mis-tagged with [extracting](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extracting))
- [What does OpenRefine offer that other data-parsing tools don't?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/515/1511)

Comment: I updated both tag description to reflect philshem answer